# MDX wrong sum on month level

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to calculate count of last 7 days with values in cube.

I write next MDX expression:

```
Count
(
  Filter
  (
    Descendants
    (
        [Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Lag(6)
      : 
        [Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember
    )
   ,[Measures].[Amount]
  )
)
```

Data is correct on day level of hierarchy, but on **month level** and other levels measure sums last 7 month value.

UPDATE
i want to show value of last day of month

example:
date        | value1 | value2
2017-01-01  | 5      | 4
2017-01-02  | 4      | 3
2017-01-03  | 3      | 2
.....
2017-01-31  | 7      |1     <--- on month level i wan't show this

Comment: if you have month level selected what would you like this measure to show? ....so say in row 1 it shows Nov-16, in row 2 shows Dec-16 and in row 3 shows Jan-17: then in column 2 you have the above measure - what should it show?

Comment: Just to make things clear: do you want to get last 7 days of the current month?

Answer (score 0):

You can get last seven days of the month with the help of `lastchild`. It will help you get the last day of the month. So for the month level you can use:

```
Count (
    Filter ( 

            {[Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember.lastchild.Lag(6) :
            [Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember.lastchild}
         ,[Measures].[Amount]
    )
)
```

Using DESCENDANTS is not appropriate here as it returns the set containing all child members of that hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but maybe something like the following

```
COUNT(
  //to find the members with values use nonempty
  NONEMPTY( 
    //find the last date in a set
    TAIL(  
      EXISTS(  //find the dates associated to the currentmember 
        [Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember
       ,[Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date Hierarchy].MEMBERS
      )
    ).ITEM(0).LAG(6)
    :
    TAIL(  //find the last date
      EXISTS(  //find the dates associated to the currentmember 
        [Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember
       ,[Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Date Hierarchy].MEMBERS
      )
    ).ITEM(0)
    , [Measures].[Amount]  
  )
)
```

I rigged up a test against Adventure Works cube.

This is if Month is selected:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[X] AS 
    Count
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
          Tail
          (
            Exists
            (
              [Date].[Calendar].[Date].MEMBERS
             ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
            )
          ).Item(0).Lag(6)
        : 
          Tail
          (
            Exists
            (
              [Date].[Calendar].[Date].MEMBERS
             ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
            )
          ).Item(0)
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,[Measures].[X]
    } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2007]&[7]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2008]&[6] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

It returns 7 as expected:

[image]

If I change to daily on axis 1:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[X] AS 
    Count
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
          Tail
          (
            Exists
            (
              [Date].[Calendar].[Date].MEMBERS
             ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
            )
          ).Item(0).Lag(6)
        : 
          Tail
          (
            Exists
            (
              [Date].[Calendar].[Date].MEMBERS
             ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
            )
          ).Item(0)
       ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
     ,[Measures].[X]
    } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070701]
    : 
      [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20080630] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

[image]

Comment: on month this expression work right, but on day level i see 0

Comment: @Elrengil forgot about this answer - was meaning to try testing it on AdvWrks

Comment: @Elrengil seems to work ok in AdvWrks - you might need to switch the arguments around inside the EXISTS function as I got them the wrong way around in my first attempt